# sklearn cosine_distances returns negative values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have used the sklearn [cosine_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distances.html) as below. Why does 'dist_desc' return negative values, even for the same objects, item0 vs item0 ?

```
tfidf_vectorizer_desc = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem)
tfidf_matrix_desc = tfidf_vectorizer_desc.fit_transform(descriptions) 
dist_desc = pairwise.cosine_distances(tfidf_matrix_desc)
```

Comment: Don't you know that performing operations with floating point you can obtain small values instead of zero (including small negative values)?

Comment: o yes! i use the clip function to handle these values : distance = np.clip(dist_desc,0,1)

Comment: You should use `distance = np.clip(dist_desc,0,2)` cause cosine distance lies in interval [0, 2].

Comment: Can you please explain why the interval is 0-2, not 0-1? The max value is 1 in my distance numpy array => i,j = np.unravel_index(dist_desc.argmax(), dist_desc.shape)
print(dist_desc[i,j])

Comment: [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) ranges from −1 meaning exactly opposite, to 1 meaning exactly the same, with 0 indicating orthogonality (decorrelation), and in-between values indicating intermediate similarity or dissimilarity. And Cosine distance = 1 - Cosine similarity. Your case is just a special case.